# iPhone - cannot get int put into UIButton

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uibutton

I am assuming this is just because I am very tired..but for some reason I cannot get my **UIBUTTONS** to get filled with the numbers that are generated. The numbers are randomly generated except for the answer. I am sure it is something simple. Thanks!

```
- (void)determineQ {
    first = arc4random() % 1000;
    second = arc4random() % 1000;
    wrong1 = arc4random() % 1000;
    wrong2 = arc4random() % 1000;
    wrong3 = arc4random() % 1000;
    while (first < second) {
        first = arc4random() % 1000;
    }
    [question setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %d = ?", first, second]];
    answer = first - second;
    NSLog(@"%d - %d = %d", first, second, answer);
    correctLetter = arc4random() % 100;
    if (correctLetter <= 25) {
        [ans2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", answer] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong1] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans3 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong2] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans4 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong3] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        NSLog(@"The answer is A");
    } else if (correctLetter <= 50) {
        [ans1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong1] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", answer] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans3 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong2] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans4 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong3] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        NSLog(@"The answer is B");
    } else if (correctLetter <= 75) {
        [ans1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong1] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong2] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans3 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", answer] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans4 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong3] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        NSLog(@"The answer is C");
    } else if (correctLetter <= 100) {
        [ans1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong1] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong2] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans3 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wrong3] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [ans4 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", answer] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        NSLog(@"The answer is D");
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry I had accidentally put UILabels, I meant UIButtons.

Comment: What error do you get? Aren't `first` and `second` a float and therefore should be `[question setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f - %.0f = ?", first, second]];`

Comment: first and second are actually ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I should not have been waiting for a Control Event in the forState, it should have been this

```
    [ans2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", answer] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3):

Arcrandom generates float or double, try cast each to int like this:

```
 [ans2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ((int)answer)] forState:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UILabel`. use the `setText` instead of `setTitle`,

```
    [ans2 settext:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", answer]];
```

OR

```
ans2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", answer];
```

Comment: I meant UIButtons, and accidentally put UILabels :/

Comment: @Muller :OK,please be careful while posting the question.